# Match every Quoted String that DOES NOT contain a substring

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Multiline Test string:

```
dkdkdkdk dkdkdkdk dkdkdkd dkdkdkd "hello" dkdkdkdkdk dkdkdk "goodbye.hello"  dkdkdkd kdkdkd kdkdkdk "hello.goodbye.hello" dddd "test" ssss "http:x-y.f/z/z" "" "."
"http:/dkdkd/dkdkdk/dkdkdkdkdkdk.g"
```

I want to match every quoted string that contains "`hello`"

This matches every quoted string

```
\"(.+?)\"
```

This matches every quoted string that contains hello in it

```
\"(.*?)hello(.*?)\"
```

But this, does not match every quoted string that DOES NOT contain hello

```
\"(.*?)(?!hello)(.*?)\"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial answer is to need to apply the negative lookahead every time the dot matches, like so:

```
\"((?!hello).)*?\"
```

However there is a problem with this regular expression in targets that contain more than one quoted string -- the space between the closing quote of one string and the opening string of another quote is also a "quoted string" to this expression.

My suggestion is therefore to extract all quoted strings from your target using a simple `"[^"]*"` pattern, and then evaluate each match for the word(s) you want to disallow.

Comment: Better use `"[^"]*"` instead of `".*?"`.

Comment: @Gumbo I don't see what difference that makes?

Comment: @Daniel Vandersluis: It avoids unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\"((?!hello).)*?\"
```

Comment: That's what I came up with at first, but I deleted my answer because it's got a problem; in the test string it won't match `"hello"`, but instead it'll match `" dkdkdkdkdk dkdkdk "`

Comment: Better use `"[^"]*"` instead of `".*?"`.